# ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in Hasmany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I am trying to access the Brand of a Vehicle through a HasMany relationship and receive the Property error, how can I fix it?

Migrations

Vehicles

```
Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Brands

```
  Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('vehicles_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Models

Vehicles

```
 public function Brands()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Brand::class,'vehicles_id');
    }
```

Brand

```
 public function Vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class,'vehicles_id');
    }
```

Method

```
 $V = Vehicle::find($id);
       dd($V->Brands->name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have relationship the incorrect way.
In your current code One brand (BMW) can be attached only to one vehicle. But in reality it is the other way. Vehicle belongs to one Brand, but one Brand can have multiple Vehicles.

Just flip the relationship

```
Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->integer('year');
    $table->string('color');
    $table->foreignId('brand_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');;
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Foreign key should be in vehicles table

Vehicle belongs to Brand

```
// Models/Vehicle.php

// singular, because vehicle belong only to one Brand
public function brand()  
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

Brand has many vehicles

```
// Models/Brand.php

// plural because one Brand has many vehicles
public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class,'vehicles_id');
}
```

Then in you controller:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::with('brand')->find($id);
dd($vehicle->brand->name);
```